# How do I customize the Admin page of a Django project?

Tags: django

Greetings admired senior developers! Newbie developer here to ask for some help!

I'm currently using Django as my framework program to build a website that gathers movie data from a certain search engine's api and provide users with movie recommendations based on reviews and rank.

The basic structure of the project will be as follows; Movie app, which receives movie data from an api and stores them, and Accounts app, an app that takes care of all the tasks regarding user activities such as signups and logins.

As for the maintenance of the server, my plan is to use the well-designed Admin page of Django to apply changes and updates to user data as well as movie data.

The problem here is that the default Admin page doesn't include the feature that allows me to get movie data from a specific api and apply it to the database of the Movie app (into the Movie model, that is).

Therefore, I'm thinking I would need to customize the Admin page itself and this is the very part where I need your help.

I've been searching all over starting off from official Django websites to other people's blogs and articles to find out how I can do this, but still couldn't get to the answer yet.

I know that it would be too much to ask you to write down the whole code for me, so I'm just hoping that you could maybe give me some words of advice or a simple draft on how I can get this to happen.

Or if you happen to know of a good website that has some useful information related to my problem (websites with some decent pictures would be nice), I would be very grateful if you gave me the link to it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem here is that the default Admin page doesn't include the feature that allows me to get movie data from a specific api and apply it to the database of the Movie app (into the Movie model, that is).

You wan't to consume an api with movie data and update your database / movie model with the data you receive from the api?

I'm using Django custom commands to consume an api and update my database. My webserver runs this custom command regularly with a cronjob. Maybe this is a solution for you?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Whoa! Though I haven't given it a try yet, I get this feeling this just might be the very answer that I was looking for! Thank you so much for your help!